# How do you write a scene in a transcript or script with a reworked version of a song with dialogue interruptions?

Tags: creative-writing, script

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy-vM5fPbR0

How do you write a scene in a transcript or script with a reworked version of a song with dialogue interruptions? Look at the scene, but imagine she's getting interrupted twice and the second characters comment or talks, how do you write this in a transcript or a script? You sometimes see "Ellie sings 'Take on Me'", but in this case if she's getting interrupted and the second character talks while she's doing it and you want to describe what Ellie does while playing like looking at the character, smiling, etc. It's difficult to think of a good way to do this. Could you give us some simple examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First explain that that's what is happening, and then style the two things differently.

**Example:**

As the song played, they laughed and joked about each line.

*Gather all you children round*

"What is this, a fairy tale?"

*To hear the unmistakeable sound*

"Eh, I could mistake it for the bleating of a goat."

*Of all the mothers and fathers round*

"Sounds like her parents were fat, am I right?"

Etc.